# iPhone - JSONKit - Working, but am I using it right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a little bit of deserialisation using JSONKit. It is working, but what I have written feels pretty clunky. Can anyone suggest some improvements please :)

```
    //call web service with url and staff id
    NSString *result = [MobileAppDelegate webServiceExecuteGetSingleWithId:StaffId
    atUrl:@"XXXXXXXX"];

    //create NSDictionary from JSON return type
    NSDictionary *items = [result objectFromJSONString];

    NSArray *ar = (NSArray*)[items objectForKey:@"SummaryJsonResult"];

    for(int i = 0; i < [ar count]; i++){
        NSDictionary *tmpDict = (NSDictionary*)[ar objectAtIndex:i];
        AlertItem *tmpItem = [[AlertItem alloc] init];
        tmpItem.Description = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"Description"];
        tmpItem.NumItems = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"ItemCount"];
        tmpItem.ModuleGroup = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"ModuleGroup"];
        tmpItem.StaffID = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"StaffID"];
        tmpItem.status - [tmpDict  objectForKey:@"Status"];
        [array addObject: tmpItem];
        [tmpItem release];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's essentially how you have to do it.  You can clean things up a little bit:

Use a `for-in` loop:

```
for (NSDictionary *tmpDict in [items objectForKey:@"SummaryJsonResult"]) {
    ...
```

Refactor creating an `AlertItem` from the dictionary into a factory method:

```
+ (AlertItem *)alertItemWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    AlertItem *item = [[self alloc] init];
    ...do the same stuff you do in the loop
    return [item autorelease];
}

... then in the loop you just do:
[array addObject:[AlertItem alertItemWithDictionary:tempDict]];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I was wondering if there is a way round going from NSDictionary, to NSArray then back to NSDictionary. Its seems like there should be some sort of object which would do for all three?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems as if you're executing your request synchronously, which is usually a bad idea. If you're running this on the main thread, you're blocking all user interaction until the request has completed.

Your code also doesn't handle any malformed data. Your app will crash if any of the objects in your JSON is of a different type than you expect. If "SummaryJsonResult" would point to a dictionary instead of an array, you'd get an "unrecognized selector" exception when trying to send it an `objectForKey:` message. You can guard against this by using `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: OK thanks for this. I will change it to an async request. Is there any particularly good way of getting data out of json if you don't know its exact format. I am calling my own web service so I have control over what is returned, but it would be nice if there was another way.

Comment: The thing is with the async request, is that I am using the array to populate a UITableView, so if I do an asyc request, won't it start trying to populate the table view before the data array has been populated...I assume this will cause a null pointer?

Comment: You could just initialize it as an empty array. You don't even have to do that, because instance variables are automatically initialized to nil and sending a message to nil (`count` in this case) returns 0 or nil, depending on context.